# Android app work on device but not samsung device

Tags: android

I have develop an android app which work on Sony, Google Nexus, Oppo and few devices but not Samsung device.

Whenever i use samsung device to run the app, it will crash at certain function.

I have tried different android version for the devices above. But still, only samsung device not working well with the app.

I did google but found no answer. Any idea about it guys?

**Update**

This is 1 of the function not work:

```
public void onClickProduct(View view){
    ImageView ImageIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.product_Button);
    ImageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.products_b_reverse);  
    startActivity(new Intent(Home.this, ProductServiceIndicator.class));    
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.flipcard_from_middle, R.anim.flipcard_to_middle);
    finish();       
}
```

And here are the log car

```
08-29 10:17:59.891: W/dalvikvm(9042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a0da0) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Process: com.toppan.toppan_android_v1, PID: 9042 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:33) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2176) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1317) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1514) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1201) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6404) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): ... 47 more 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872) 
08-29 10:17:59.891: W/dalvikvm(9042): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a0da0) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Process: com.toppan.toppan_android_v1, PID: 9042 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:33) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1053) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5365) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2176) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1317) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1514) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1201) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6404) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): ... 47 more 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872) 
08-29 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.Home" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/top_pannel_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/top01" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/top_pannel_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/login_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerLogOutButton"
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/clicktohome"
        android:onClick="onClickViewLogout"
        android:scaleType="fitEnd"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/logout_gray_01" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mypanelpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.TouchHighlightImageButton
        android:id="@+id/locate_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:onClick="locate_us_viewPager"
        android:contentDescription="@string/locate_gray" 
        android:src="@drawable/locate01" />

    <com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.TouchHighlightImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/locate_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/locate_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_marginRight="-72dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/messages_gray" 
        android:src="@drawable/messages01" />

    <com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.TouchHighlightImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/message_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/message_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_marginRight="-72dp"
        android:onClick="home_viewPager_onclick"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_gray" 
        android:src="@drawable/home01" />

    <com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.TouchHighlightImageButton
        android:id="@+id/contact_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/home_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_marginRight="-72dp"
        android:onClick="contact_us_viewPager"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contactus" 
        android:src="@drawable/contacts01" />

    <com.toppan.toppan_android_v1.TouchHighlightImageButton
        android:id="@+id/more_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contact_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contact_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_marginRight="-73dp"
        android:onClick="moreOnClickViewPager"
        android:contentDescription="@string/moregray" 
        android:src="@drawable/more01" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/locate_button_viewpager"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="10dip" 
        app:fillColor="#77D9D3"
        app:pageColor="#ffffff"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: More info? Can you provide a crash log? OS version etc?

Comment: No code, no error description, not even the device description. It's absolutely impossible to even guess. Just the manifest alone could provide hundreds of different possibilities for an app to not work on a not described Samsung device. Sorry, but I had to downvote your question.

Comment: Check your stacktrace. It'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Your stack trace is difficult to read. Please put it inside a code block.

Comment: Looking at your stack trace: 10:17:59.901: E/AndroidRuntime(9042): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class

This means the line #35 of the xml that you tried to inflate has problems (maybe a typo or something like that). It's being called from your PhoneLayoutInflater class line 56

Comment: Hi lucasdc, i added the xml above, i have checked the xml file but still i cant find any error on line #35

Comment: Looking at your log output, I would guess it is the `OutOfMemoryError`. How big are the `drawable` resources you are loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has triggered an out of memory error, probably by loading a graphic asset that is much too big. It's in your stack trace near the bottom, and the other error mentioned is caused indirectly by running out of memory.

Out of memory errors can be tricky to trace because the sequence of events is

1. Your code uses up most memory with a large allocation
2. At some later point another attempt to allocate memory is made (probably in some system library)
3. You get a stack trace that doesn't point to the line causing the problem, but to the system library.

So you would have to look at large graphic assets (could be the bitmap drawable in your code block) to find out what to fix.

The fact that it is working now on some phones is a red herring. This crash could occur on any device.

Comment: yes! tried using small size graphics to replace the large size graphics and it did work fine. Thanks!